# SonarQube Language sonar.lang.patterns error

Tags: sonarqube

Our Sonar Build Environment details as follows:

```
* SonarQube Server Version - 5.6.6 (64-Bit). 
* Sonar Client Build Operating System – Windows-7 (64-Bit). 
* Sonar-scanner- Version - 3.0.3.778.
* sonar-cxx-plugin-0.9.7.jar
* sonar-csharp-plugin Version -5.11.0.1761.
* sonar-objective-c-plugin-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
* Source Code Language: C# and C++
```

Our SonarQube server is centralized server, So have installed (cxx-plugin, objective-c-plugin and csharp-plugin)

**Current Problem:**

When we scan the code, if fails with below error. Since we have multiple language (C# and C++) code, Both the language has to be scanned at a time.

`ERROR: Caused by: Language of file 'workspace/HS30/baseclasses/ametex.h' can not be decided as the file matches patterns of both sonar.lang.patterns.c++ : **/*.cxx,**/*.cpp,**/*.cc,**/*.c,**/*.hxx,**/*.hpp,**/*.hh,**/*.h and sonar.lang.patterns.objectivec : **/*.h,**/*.m`

sonar.language=cs,c++ (Tried but didn't work)

So kindly help us to resolve the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a question of which language "claims" `.h` files. Only one language can claim any given file extension and currently you have two languages claiming `.h`, so the scanner can't figure out which analyzer to give those files to, and gives up.

Specifically, from your error message:

```
the file matches patterns of both sonar.lang.patterns.c++ : **/*.cxx,**/*.cpp,**/*.cc,**/*.c,**/*.hxx,**/*.hpp,**/*.hh,**/*.h and sonar.lang.patterns.objectivec : **/*.h,**/*.m
```

You have both `cxx` and `objectivec` claiming `.h`. You must remove the extension from one of those two lists.

Go to (Global) **Administration > [Language] > [Language] file suffixes** to edit the extensions claimed by each language, and remove `.h` from one or both languages.

Make sure that you do not leave either of these fields blank. If left blank, the default value (which includes `.h`) will be used.

Comment: Hi Ann,

Under Administration-->General Settings--> Category tab

For Launague C# "File suffixes" already empty, Nothing is configured.However "Ignore header comments" also set to Default.

Even for C++ (Community) also Source files suffixes and Header files suffixes set as empty.

Comment: Since we are using C# and C++ languages, tried below in analysis properties file, But still it fails with same error.

sonar.cxx.suffixes.headers=.hxx,.hpp,.hh,.h
sonar.cxx.suffixes.sources=.cxx,.cpp,.cc,.c
sonar.cs.file.suffixes=.cs

ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: Language of file 'workspace/HS30/baseclasses/amtex.h' can not be decided as the file matches patterns of both sonar.lang.patterns.c++ : **/*.cxx,**/*.cpp,**/*.cc,**/*.c,**/*.hxx,**/*.hpp,**/*.hh,**/*.h and sonar.lang.patterns.objectivec : **/*.h,**/*.m

Comment: Even sonar.cs.file.suffixes=.cs
sonar.cxx.file.suffixes=.h,.cxx didn't work.

Comment: see my expansion @Mohan.S

Comment: Hi Ann, Under Administration-->General Settings--> Category tab For Launague Objective-C (Community) "File suffixes" column already empty only.

Comment: Already for C++ (Community) Source files suffixes and Header files suffixes already empty. Now both are empty only, My languages are C# and C++, i need to scan both the languages along with C++ header files as well. So kindly guide me.

Comment: See my further expansion @Mohan.S

Comment: Dear Ann, Yes it is working now. Thank you very much for the continue support and help :) :)

Answer (score 2):

I do `sonar.lang.patterns.c=""` to empty the C extensions, and only keep the C++ ones. You need to know which one you want to keep, for instance `sonar.lang.patterns.objectivec=""` to remove the objectiveC ones.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, the easiest approach would be configuring the patterns so that *.h files are only matched by one language, i.e. by setting the option *sonar.lang.patterns.objectivec* empty.

Indeed, that would be sacrifice analysis for ObjectiveC, maybe you can rethink your project structure or run two Sonar builds that scan both languages individually?